# Minimum API level for using android EncryptedSharedPreference?

Tags: android, encryption

What is the minimum API level required for android encryptedShared preference?

I'm using following dependency

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

My minimum API level is 21, I've read that minimum API required for shared preference is 23.

If in my code can I put a logic like below API 23 use regular sharedPreference(I use server to store critical data) and I will never initialize encrypted shared preference and in API23+ I use encrypt shared preference.

Will my code compile and run without any issue in below API23?

Comment: Support for API level 21 is available https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#security-crypto-1.1.0-alpha01 , and yes you can create your preferences by checking OS version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will my code compile and run without any issue in below API23?

Yes

For creating `SharedPreferences` OR `EncryptedSharedPreferences` on with API Level check

```
object PrefMgr {
  private var preferences: SharedPreferences? = null

  init {
    preferences = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
            context,
            APP_PREF_FILE,
            MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                .build(),
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        )
    } else {
        context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage/issues/22#issuecomment-655130101: add in `AndroidManifest`: `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" />` if you use API level < 21.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @CoolMind

Comment: Thanks for an updated code of `EncryptedSharedPreferences` creation. See also [migration to EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://medium.com/att-israel/how-to-migrate-to-encrypted-shared-preferences-cc4105c03518).